# How do I create a numpy array of all True or all False?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, numpy-ndarray

In Python, how do I create a numpy array of arbitrary shape filled with all `True` or all `False`?

Answer (score 426, accepted):

**The answer:**

```py
numpy.full((2, 2), True)
```

---

**Explanation:**

numpy creates arrays of all ones or all zeros very easily:

e.g. `numpy.ones((2, 2))` or `numpy.zeros((2, 2))`

Since `True` and `False` are represented in Python as `1` and `0`, respectively, we have only to specify this array should be boolean using the optional `dtype` parameter and we are done:

```py
numpy.ones((2, 2), dtype=bool)
```

returns:

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

**UPDATE: 30 October 2013**

Since numpy [version 1.8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.8.0), we can use `full` to achieve the same result with syntax that more clearly shows our intent (as fmonegaglia points out):

```
numpy.full((2, 2), True, dtype=bool)
```

**UPDATE: 16 January 2017**

Since at least numpy [version 1.12](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/index.html), `full` automatically casts to the `dtype` of the second parameter, so we can just write:

```
numpy.full((2, 2), True)
```

Comment: dtype=int initialized array cannot be used for array element selection.

Comment: This works. However, be careful because as @Jichao says, `a=np.ones((2,2))` followed by `a.dtype=bool` does NOT work.

Comment: answer assumes that np.ones or np.zeros with dtype bool have to cast int array as boolean. Is this assumption true? I think it creates boolean array and doesn't create int array first and then cast. Kindly correct this answer if I am right

Answer (score 108):

```
numpy.full((2,2), True, dtype=bool)
```

Comment: +1 I think this should be the accepted answer. It seems more natural to fill an array with bools, than to fill it with numbers to cast them to bools.

Comment: The `ones` and `zeros` answers do not construct an array of integers. They build an array of bools directly.

Comment: Is `numpy.full((2,2), True)` an equivalent?

Comment: It is in numpy 1.12+. I dont remember whether it applies to former versions either

Comment: Surly dtype is stored separately from the data itself when possible? I can't imagine numpy doing any heavy lifting to convert `int 1` to `bool True`.

Comment: @BallpointBen: dtype and data are separate, but data representation is dependent on the dtype. Converting an array of integers to an array of booleans requires creating an entirely new array with an entirely new data buffer and performing elementwise conversion. (None of the existing answers do an int array to bool array conversion, though.)

Comment: full tends to be much slower than ones or zeros

Answer (score 33):

`ones` and `zeros`, which create arrays full of ones and zeros respectively, take an optional `dtype` parameter:

```
>>> numpy.ones((2, 2), dtype=bool)
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> numpy.zeros((2, 2), dtype=bool)
array([[False, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 9):

If it doesn't have to be writeable you can create such an array with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy-broadcast-to):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.broadcast_to(True, (2, 5))
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

If you need it writable you can also create an empty array and [`fill`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) it yourself:

```
>>> arr = np.empty((2, 5), dtype=bool)
>>> arr.fill(1)
>>> arr
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

These approaches are only alternative suggestions. In general you should stick with `np.full`, `np.zeros` or `np.ones` like the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 7):

benchmark for Michael Currie's answer

```
import perfplot

bench_x = perfplot.bench(
    n_range= range(1, 200),
    setup  = lambda n: (n, n),
    kernels= [
        lambda shape: np.ones(shape, dtype= bool),
        lambda shape: np.full(shape, True)
    ],
    labels = ['ones', 'full']
)

bench_x.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to see that `full` has only a fixed time penalty, and not a time penalty that scales with the size of the array.  So the larger the array, the less important this difference becomes.

Answer (score 5):

Quickly ran a timeit to see, if there are any differences between the `np.full` and `np.ones` version.

Answer: **No**

```py
import timeit

n_array, n_test = 1000, 10000
setup = f"import numpy as np; n = {n_array};"

print(f"np.ones: {timeit.timeit('np.ones((n, n), dtype=bool)', number=n_test, setup=setup)}s")
print(f"np.full: {timeit.timeit('np.full((n, n), True)', number=n_test, setup=setup)}s")
```

Result:

```
np.ones: 0.38416870904620737s
np.full: 0.38430388597771525s
```

**IMPORTANT**

Regarding the post about `np.empty` (and I cannot comment, as my reputation is too low):

**DON'T DO THAT. DON'T USE `np.empty` to initialize an all-`True` array**

As the array is empty, the memory is not written and there is no guarantee, what your values will be, e.g.

```py
>>> print(np.empty((4,4), dtype=bool))
[[ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False False]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> a = numpy.full((2,4), True, dtype=bool)
>>> a[1][3]
True
>>> a
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

numpy.full(Size, Scalar Value, Type). There is other arguments as well that can be passed, for documentation on that, check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html

Comment: Well, [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35224478/5393381) already answered using `np.full` - more than one year ago!